# How to create a new database in oracle DB developer vm

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a new database (a container database) in oracle db developer virtual machine. Its been failing because I've logged in as sys from the default pluggable database provided by the vm. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: do you want a new pluggable database, or an entire new instance (container database)?

Comment: I want to create an entire new instance.

Comment: Use the database creation assistant (dbca)... Easy wizard interface